System.ArgumentNullException: MongoDb connection string is not provided. (Parameter 'connectionString') asp.net Core Docker-compose
My ASP.NET Core application runs fine locally, but when I run it in a Docker container, it cannot find the MongoDB connection string and throws the error System.ArgumentNullException: MongoDB connection string is not provided.
My Docker-compose file looks like this:
version: '3.8'
services:
  BooksApiApp:
    image: booksapi
    container_name: booksapiApp
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./BooksApi/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5271
    ports:
      - 5271:80
    networks:
      - mybridgenetwork
    restart: always

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - mybridgenetwork
    volumes:
      - mymongovolume:/data/db
      - mymongovolume:/data/configdb
    restart: always

  UsersApiApp:
    image: usersapi
    container_name: usersapiApp
    depends_on:
      - BooksApiApp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./UsersApi/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5056  
    ports:
      - 5056:80
    restart: always 

networks:
  mybridgenetwork:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mymongovolume:

My connection string looks like this:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MongoDb": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "UsersDb": "Server=localhost;Database=UsersDb;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }

How can I fix this error?

I realized that there was an error in the connection string. The correct version should be:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "MongoDb": "mongodb://mongodb:27017"
  }

